# Yii 2 Fields function in Active Record Models

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on REST API under Yii2, however I have an issue with what the model should return per different actions.

For example in listing actions I need to for example to return 4 attributes and for the details action I need to return 10 attributes from the same model.

What is the best or standard way in Yii2 to implement this.

**Example:**

**/articles**

return [id, title, image, date]

**/articles/7**

return [id, title, image, date, author, likes, last_review]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just write methods in your model.

```
class MyModel extends ActiveRecord
{
    private static $fieldset_1 = [
       'id', 'title', 'image', 'date'
    ];

    private static $fieldset_2 = [
       'id', 'title', 'image', 'date', 'author', 'likes', 'last_review'
    ];

    public static function get(int $id)
    {
        if($id > 0) {
           return static::find()
              ->select(self::$fieldset_1)
              ->where(['id' => $id])
              ->asArray()
              ->one();
        }
   }

   public static function getList()
   {
      return static::find()
           ->select(self::$fieldset_2)
           ->asArray()
           ->all();
   }

}
```

In Controller

```
class MyController extends Controller{

    public function actionListing(){
        return $this->asJson(MyModel::getList());
    }

    public function actionDetails($id){
        return $this->asJson(MyModel::get((int)$id));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**for /article/7 :**

```
public function actionView($id)
{
   return User::findOne($id);
}
```

or

```
public function actionView($id)
{
   return User::find()->select([id, title, image, date, author, likes,last_review])->one();
}
```

**for /articles :**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   return User::find()->select([id, title, image, date])->all();
}
```